Error in import default from css file using vite and webpack
I'm trying to migrate from Create react app to Vite. But now I have the following error in on of the packages that I use in my React app.
[vite] connecting... client.ts:19:8 [vite] connected. client.ts:175:14 Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'http://localhost:.../@fs/home/.../.../node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css' doesn't provide an export named: 'default' styles.js:5:7
I'm using react + vite + webpack + typescript,
Does anyone already had this problem before?
I followed this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-migrate-from-create-react-app-to-vite/
I already tried to change my web pack config but nothing works. This import is in the package flag-icon.css so i should not just change this code, but my configuration instead.

Can you share your webpack config? Let me know where that flag-icon.css file is imported. I think it might be a version issue.

@FirstArachne `module.exports = {
resolve: {
fallback: { buffer: require.resolve("buffer/")},
},
test: /.svg(?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/,
use: [
{ loader: 'babel-loader' },
{
loader: '@svgr/webpack',
options: {
babel: false,
icon: true,
},
},
],
};
` and another plugin called react-flag-icon-css is importing the /flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css
